# Remove a facet_grid panel derived from NA factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO"),
  log2fold.change= c(0.15,3,2,1,0.4),
  neg.log.p.value= c(2,5,0.35,6,0.3),
  gene.class= c("1","1","2","2",NA),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
```

And I have plotted it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(log2fold.change, neg.log.p.value)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ gene.class)
```

[image: plot]

Is there a way to omit the last panel that contains the factor `NA`?

Comment: `ggplot(subset(df, !is.na(gene.class)), aes(log2fold.change, neg.log.p.value)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(. ~ gene.class)`